# Set version limit per model in Papertrail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Is there a way to limit the number of versions, per model, in Papertrail?

E.g., I know I can set a global limit with

```
PaperTrail.config.version_limit = 3
```

But I don't see a way to set that per model, with something like

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :limit => [10]
end
```

I also don't want to just limit the number of versions saved (to say ten) but have it so only the latest ten are saved (same as with the `config` version setting).

Comment: I'm using subclassing to achieve different configuration for different purposes like described here: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#custom-version-classes hower you'll end up having different version tables and I'm not sure if that's something you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer you want:

Add constant "PAPER_TRAIL_VERSION_LIMIT" to your Article model like below

```
# models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  # 10 mean you article will have 11 version include 'create' version
  PAPER_TRAIL_VERSION_LIMIT = 10
end
```

Add below codes to the bottom of PaperTrail config file

```
# /config/initializers/paper_trail.rb
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    private
    def enforce_version_limit!
      limit = PaperTrail.config.version_limit
      # This is the key custom line
      limit = item.class::PAPER_TRAIL_VERSION_LIMIT  if item.class.const_defined?("PAPER_TRAIL_VERSION_LIMIT")
      return unless limit.is_a? Numeric
      previous_versions = sibling_versions.not_creates
      return unless previous_versions.size > limit
      excess_versions = previous_versions - previous_versions.last(limit)
      excess_versions.map(&:destroy)
    end
  end
end
```

Enjoy it ! :D

Comment: Wouldn't this be more generic with `if item.class.const_defined?("PAPER_TRAIL_VERSION_LIMIT")` instead of `if item.is_a? Article`

Comment: Hi @BrunoPeres, your idea make it better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As for Paper Trail 11.0.0, limiting the number of versions created supported by gem out from the box:
https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2e-limiting-the-number-of-versions-created

For example:

```
# At most 3 versions (2 updates, 1 create). Overrides global version_limit.
has_paper_trail limit: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following initializer:

```
# /config/initializers/paper_trail.rb
module PaperTrail
  module VersionConcern
    private

    def enforce_version_limit!
      limit = defined?(version_limit) ? version_limit : PaperTrail.config.version_limit
      return unless limit.is_a? Numeric
      previous_versions = sibling_versions.not_creates
      return unless previous_versions.size > limit
      excess_versions = previous_versions - previous_versions.last(limit)
      excess_versions.map(&:destroy)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can simply define `version_limit` in any model you want to specify an alternative limit for.

```
def version_limit
  20
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the `if:` syntax to selectively turn off paper trail:

```
has_paper_trail :if => Proc.new { |model| model.versions.count > 10 }
```

Specifics from the docs: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#choosing-when-to-save-new-versions

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for; this would save the first ten versions and then just stop, versus saving the latest ten.